# Download and launch another app within the base app- iphone

Tags: iphone

I wish to develop an app which based on a barcode downloads another set of code/app and executes the required action. The base app doesn't have the flow of the action coded but just the identification parameter and inputs on which app to download.

Is this possible?

Comment: yes it is possible, but your title is terrible, i says nothing about your problem/initension

Comment: maybe possible, but likely will not pass Apple's review process.  There are rules against executing downloaded code

Answer (score 3):

It depends on whether you want app store approval and what the 'code' is.  The review guidelines say, "2.7  Apps that download code in any way or form will be rejected."

On the other hand, a web page often has Javascript code associated with it and a web view can execute that.

It depends on some more details and whether you're intending to use the store.